# Javascript Validation in asp.net MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

My problem is when page is loaded first time,alert(1) and alert(2) pops up, but when I click on my save button alert(3) don't pops up but validation message is shown(doesn't meter if I fill correct or wrong my dropdownlist)and everything is saved.
I have this kind of JS:

```
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert(1);
            PassWayValidators();
            $('#documents_TravelDocumentDocumentPass_PassDate').datepicker();           

        });

        function PassWayValidators() {
            alert(2);
            $.validator.addMethod('PassWayValidator',
                    function (value, element) {
                        alert(3);
                    }, 'Please Inert Valid Numbers');

            $("#documents_TravelDocumentDocumentPass_PassWayId").rules("add", {
                PassWayValidator: true
            });
        }
    </script>
    <...Some Code Here...>
         <div class="TravelDocumentDocumentPassCommentInner">
                                <span>გადაცემის ფორმა
                                    <br />
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => documents.TravelDocumentDocumentPass.PassWayId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DocumentPassTypeList, String.Empty, isDisabled)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => documents.TravelDocumentDocumentPass.PassWayId, "*")
                                </span>
                            </div>
    <...Some Code Here too... and>
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing a custom validator, I see two things right off the bat that needs to be corrected.

First, you need to call `PassWayValidators();` outside of $(document).ready(). I'm not 100% sure that it is necessary, but I think that is the only way I was able to get custom validation to work.

```
PassWayValidators();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#documents_TravelDocumentDocumentPass_PassDate').datepicker();                     
});
```

Then, you need to configure your dropdown to make sure it calls your validation function with by specifying certain html attributes.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
    documents.TravelDocumentDocumentPass.PassWayId, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DocumentPassTypeList, 
    String.Empty, 
    new { 
        data_val = "true",
        data_val_PassWayValidator = "Please insert valid numbers"
    })
```

Something like that. I don't know what rules("add" { }) is for, but I'm not sure if you need that. In case I missed something, here is a complete sample taken from one of my applications.

```
<!-- some form and other html and stuff -->
@Html.TextBox("Amount", null, new 
{ 
    data_val = "true", 
    data_val_required = "This field is required", 
    data_val_number = "The field must be a number",
    data_val_notBeZero = "Value must not be zero"
})

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // validators
    $.validator.addMethod("notBeZero", function (value, element)
    {
        if (Number(Math.abs(value).toFixed(2)) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }, "Value must not be zero");

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("notBeZero");
</script>
```